Are equations of motion unique?
If I have the equation of motion for a system, is it unique or might it be possible to find a different equation of motion, which describes the system equally?
(If the question isn't answerable in general, then you might have an idea if I give you my special case:

Specifically, I'd like to know whether there's a different equation of motion that describes the double pendulum since it is analytically unsolvable.)

Why, you may always convert to some alternative variables and get different equations. That won't make them analytically solvable, though.

Welcome to MSE. To avoid your question being down-voted or close-voted, the Community encourages you to follow the Code of Conduct. Please, refer to the Asking section to make your question more appealing for contributors. For starters, you might want to avoid using links to formulas and type them down yourself using MathJax. Second, you are more than welcome to share your own thoughts and ideas.

typically the physical law involved generates a differential equation with boundary conditions. If the boundary conditions are consistent then the solution of this equation will be unique.

in general the answer is no, as example see the Norton's dome... also, if you want that your model going to be a 1st or 2nd order ODE such its solutions stop moving in finite time, the ODE must have a non-linear non-lipschitz term were uniqueness could be broken, such in that place you could have the posibbility to stitch the zero solution forever after.

@Paul I have seen that argument. But how would you justify it? How do you come to that conclusion? I have no Idea. I mean sure, since Newtonian, Lagrangian, and Hamiltonian Formulation are equivalent, the solution will be the same, as long as you do it with that theory. But that doesn't exclude another (not discovered) theory that describes the system equivalently but through a different derivation, with a different DE.

I suppose relativity theory will give you something slightly different. I'm not sure if you are asking for different mathematics, different physics or both.

@Paul Yes, but relativity also gives you a different result. I'm asking if there could be a different set of DEs, which isnt a simple conversion of the original one, but spits out the same result. Or is there just one set of DEs that can give me that result.

physical laws determine the DE, so how are you going to create a new DE without changing the laws? I can't see that if you start with the solution, how you could use calculus and arrive at a different DE with possibly different boundary conditions.
